# Click Event on Certain Columns of GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` on my page. I want to set a cell click event on the EmployeeID, EmployeeName and Designation columns, but I don't want to change the Approver column which contains Approve button and also on the Image columns.

[image]

I know that I can set `e.Row.Attributes["onclick"]` in my `RowDataBound` event, but that will make the whole row selectable, which I don't want to do. Can anyone tell me how to set the cell click event on specific columns in a `GridView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
 {

          e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.gridMSDS, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);

 }
```

Comment: I would also change the cursor to the hand with the pointy finger so the user knows something will happen when they click a cell.